# JSON error while passing data from one environment to another rest api

Tags: apex, rest-api, webservices, post

I need to sync some account records between two environments of the salesforce.
I'm able to make a callout but while passing data getting a JSON error.
I'm basically serializing a list of accounts in the source, which I intend to deserialize in the destination.

Source Method:

```
List<Account> accountList = new List<Account>();
    string jsonstr = JSON.serialize(accountList);
            Http h1 = new Http();
            HttpRequest req1 = new HttpRequest();
            req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+'!sessionId');
            req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            req1.setHeader('accept','application/json');
            
            req1.setBody(jsonstr);//Send JSON body
            req1.setMethod('POST');
            req1.setEndpoint('https://test.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/accountSync');
            HttpResponse res1 = h1.send(req1);
```

Destination:

```
@HttpPost
    global static string sampleRequestMethod(string accList) {
        system.debug('>>> accList... '+accList);
        
        return 'Success';
    }
```

Comment: Do you get an error message? Please be as detailed as possible about the error you receive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the far end is using a string parameter. This means that the JSON is expected to have a top-level property that corresponds to the parameter, as in:

```
{ "accList": [ { ... }, { ... } ] }
```

You can read more about it in the [Apex REST Methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm) documentation.

To make the JSON match what's expected, do this:

```
string jsonstr = JSON.serialize(new Map<String, Object> { 'accList' => accountList });
```

---

If you want to send your JSON as is, make sure you use `RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()` instead of using the parameterized deserialization method.

```
@HttpPost
global static string sampleRequestMethod() {
  String jsonBody = RestContext.request.requestBody.toString();
  // etc //
}
```